# Find minimum-weight set of edges to remove that will make a graph acyclic

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Given a positively-weighted, undirected cyclic graph, how can I find the smallest set of edges to remove that will make the graph acyclic? The algorithm must run in O((E+V)logV) time.

I attempted to solve this, and thought of using Djikstra's algorithm (since it also runs in O(E+VlogV) time, but am quite unsure how to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, once you’ve done this, what you’re left with must be a ***maximum*** spanning tree (or maximum spanning forest, if the original graph wasn’t connected). In particular:

1. Your remaining graph must be acyclic.
2. If the deleted edges split an existing connected component into two or more CCs, then choosing to not delete an edge crossing between the two new CCs would leave an acyclic graph with lower cost to the edge deletions.
3. Since you’re going to be left with a spanning tree, you’d like the maximum possible weight in that spanning tree, which minimizes the cost of the deleted edges.

From this, see if you can find a way to compute a maximum spanning tree. As a hint, use an existing *minimum* spanning tree algorithm as a black box.